# Why am I getting the error "No available debug probes are connected" when running pyocd list for K64F mbed board?

Tags: embedded, cortex-m, udev, mbed

Details in the title really.
See below for examples.

When running `pyocd list` I get an error:

```
nicholas@nicholas-Lenovo-ideapad-720S-14IKB:~$ pyocd list
No available debug probes are connected
```

The output should be as follows:

```
0 => FRDM-K64F [k64f] boardId => 0240000034544e45001e00018aa9002b2011000097969900
```

Now, the error sometimes, although isn't doing so at the moment, redirects me to the udev page on Github. But this does not seem to solve the issue.

Some advice on this regard would be much appreciated.

I have taken a look inside the directory etc/udev/rules.d and yet my results thus far have been disappointing.

Will I have to write this udev rule myself?

This is quite a popular device so I don't understand why I would not have a udev rule automatically there.

Here is the output of the lsusb command:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:210d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0d28:0204 NXP LPC1768
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see the probe in the output of the `lsusb` command ?

Comment: @Frant Hello. Yes, and when using lsusb -D, and then selecting a device it's not giving me any information. Not just for this device mind. So I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Frant But the device even shows the bootloader file on the desktop. So I'm certain the system is picking it up somehow. Is it possible that Ubuntu distro version matters?

Comment: You don' t  have to write the rules yourself, just drop the correct [udev rules file provided by pyocd](https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD/tree/master/udev)  into the `/etc/udev/rules.d`  directory, and restart udev. I guess you should copy `50-cmsis-dap.rules`.

Comment: @Frant I'm afraid that I've already tried that to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Frant Do I have to do anything extra after adding the files that I'm missing. I have all of the files from the github PyOCD page in the folder etc/udev/rules.d.

Including 50-cmsis-dap.rules

Comment: Just make sure you restarted `udev`, or better, reboot your Linux PC. I don't think the permissions/ownerships do matter, but your may execute `chown root:root /etc/udev/rules.d/*; chmod 644 /etc/udev/rules.d/*`prior to reboot.

Comment: @Frant I haven't tried the latter that you sent regarding chown etc.

It could be that it has something to do with that.~

However, it's currently not letting me for whatever reason. Even when running as Sudo. (Example >).     

nicholas@nicholas-Lenovo-ideapad-720S-14IKB:~$ sudo chown root:root /etc/udev/rules.d/*; chmod 644 /etc/udev/rules.d/*
[sudo] password for nicholas:                 
chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/udev/rules.d/50-cmsis-dap.rules': Operation not permitted

Comment: Please augment your question with the ouput of the `lsusb` command.

Comment: You need to execute sudo for each command: `sudo chown root:root /etc/udev/rules.d/*;sudo  chmod 644 /etc/udev/rules.d/*`

Comment: @Frant Rebooted to no avail.

Here is the output of lsusb:

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e500 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:210d Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0d28:0204 NXP LPC1768
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

NXP is the device in question.

Apologies, I'm still trying to get a hang of the formatting on here :P.